# Extending a .d.ts module that is also a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphicsmagick

I'm attempting to extend (from definitely typed) locally: [gm/gm.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gm/gm.d.ts)
The module is a function as well as a namespace, and I need to add an additional invocation of the function. I want to extend the current typing

```
function m(image: string): m.State;
```

to also support

```
function m(readableStream:NodeJS.ReadableStream, image: string): m.State;
```

I'm currently running into the issue that any attempt to add the additional typing for the new function, ends up overwriting the entire module.

Ultimately I will just submit a PR for the typing, but in general I would like the ability to augment the existing typings without a need for modifying the original file.

Comment: I have the same problem. I worked around the compiler error by casting gm to any: (<any>gm)(buffer, fileName).resize(... I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: I've done something simliar `((gm as any)(buffer, filename) as gm.State)` and at that point I get code completion.  I'm going to submit a PR to fix that, but I haven't found a way to do that locally.  I have a feeling this won't be the last time.

Comment: Just added a [PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/8748) if you want to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a function overload:

```
function m(image: string): m.State;
function m(readableStream:NodeJS.ReadableStream, image: string): m.State;
```

Comment: The goal was to do this without modifying the file.  I'm not able to find a way to do what you recommend externally.

Comment: You cannot do it without modifying the file.